# How to get value that is present in attribute of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array from a response in which I need to get the value that is present in the salary attribute of args array of id Proprety attribute from each object/response. How can achieve this?

```
 var arr = [
    [
        {
            id: "alex",
            idProperty: {
                args: [
                    {
                    name: "alex_name"
                    }, 
                    { 
                    salary: "16L" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            id: "john",
            idProperty: {
                args: [
                    {
                    name: "john_name"
                    }, 
                    { 
                    salary: "14L" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   ]   
 ];
```

EDIT: thanks to every one for all the answers for the above query but how to get the same salary attribute if the structure is :

case 1 :

```
var arr = {
            [
                id: "alex",
                idProperty: {
                    args: [
                        {
                        name: "alex_name"
                        }, 
                        { 
                        salary: "16L" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            [
                id: "john",
                idProperty: {
                    args: [
                        {
                        name: "john_name"
                        }, 
                        { 
                        salary: "14L" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
     };
```

case - 2

```
var arr = [
                {
                    id: "alex",
                    idProperty: {
                        args: [
                            {
                            name: "alex_name"
                            }, 
                            { 
                            salary: "16L" 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "john",
                    idProperty: {
                        args: [
                            {
                            name: "john_name"
                            }, 
                            { 
                            salary: "14L" 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
         ];
```

I am sorry to ask if this is so simple as I am really new to react native and java script and so confused with various scenarios.

Comment: Use the combination of index and key to access it. Ex- `arr[0][0]['idProperty'].args[1].salary`

Comment: `arr[0][x]['idProperty']['args'][1]['salary'];` - replace x with item id. Ideally you'd want to clean up your object. There are too many layers.

Answer (score 0):

`Extract the 'idProperty' Object and then iterate over the args array in it`

```js
var arr = [
    [
        {
            id: "alex",
            idProperty: {
                args: [
                    {
                    name: "alex_name"
                    }, 
                    { 
                    salary: "16L" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            id: "john",
            idProperty: {
                args: [
                    {
                    name: "john_name"
                    }, 
                    { 
                    salary: "14L" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
   ]   
 ];

const accu = [];
const output = arr[0].forEach(({idProperty}) => {
    idProperty.args.forEach(({salary}) => {
        if(salary)accu.push(salary);
    });
 });

 console.log(accu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for

```
var salaries
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
   salaries[arr[i].id] = arr.idProperty.args.salary;
}
```

You'll have something like this:

```
console.log(salaries);
[
'alex':'16L',
'john':'14L'
]
```

**UPDATE**

```
_.each(arr, function (value, key) {
      salaries[value.id] = _.find(value.idProperty.args, function(o) { return o.salary != undefined; }).salary;  
});
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention in the question that I only want to use lodash functions for e.g. forEach()

Comment: @reciever I made a update in the answer. Let me know if it helped

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme thank you very much. I really appreciate if you could consider the other cases as well 

Comment: @reciever - One think i like about `javascript` is that you can access array and object in the same way. The code i posted should work on all the cases, as long as the fields dont change names. If it doesn't work, let me know. Here you can find some information about the _.each https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme, how can I achieve the same for the second case( case -2) i.e., if there are more than 1 object in the array?

Comment: @reciever I think i got what you mean =). Could you test now?

Comment: thank you very much but I can only use arrow functions and lodash es , tfunctions as @Andy answered

Comment: @reciever - Last try hahaha. How about now?

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme thanks for your patience, at least I could relate what  modifications I could do. Thanks again!!

Comment: @reciever no problem. Did you manage to solve the problem? Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try below approach -

```
var newarr = arr[0];
for(var i=0; i<newarr.length; i++)
{
    var salValue = newarr[i].idProperty.args[1].salary
    console.log('Salary value :' + salValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the nested array and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the salary object in the args array of each object. This returns an array of salary figures. I've used `find` instead of accessing the second element of the `args` array in case the salary object isn't always the second element, and some [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var arr = [[{"id":"alex","idProperty":{"args":[{"name":"alex_name"},{"salary":"16L"}]}},{"id":"john","idProperty":{"args":[{"name":"john_name"},{"salary":"14L"}]}}]];

// `map` over the inner array, destructure the args array from each object
const salaries = arr[0].map(({ idProperty: { args } }) =>

  // find the object in the args array that has the salary key
  // and return its salary value
  args.find(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'salary').salary
);

console.log(salaries);
```

Comment: it would be a great help if you can consider the cases I added.

Comment: can you please explain what is happening in your find statement find(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'salary').salary and  why is "salary" is used two times

Comment: `find` returns the object in the array the (only/first) key of which is "salary". It then extracts the value of the salary property from that object. @reciever

Comment: Also @reciever case 1 isn't valid JS, and it looks like the only change in case 2 is that there isn't a nested array so you would do `arr.map` rather than `arr[0].map`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying randomly for a long time I got answer for the case 2

```
const ids = array.map( a => return a.map(obj => obj.idProperty.args[1].salary));
```

but I am unable to achieve the answer at this point `obj.idProperty.args[1].salary` without using arg[1] as Andy got using lodash.

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json" this might be helpful for beginners.